# ERROR: no instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal `1'

Tags: haskell, monads

`insert_at`  insert an element `e` into a list `xs` in specific location `n`

`test`getting `Left` if `n` less than 0

`test2` getting `Left` if  `n` larger than `xs`'s length or **The type `e` isn't match the element's type in list`xs`**. Otherwise passing `Right xs` to the next.

```
import Data.Typeable

insert_at :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
insert_at e xs n = a++(e:b) where
    t = splitAt n xs
    a = fst t
    b = snd t 
test :: (Ord a, Num a) => b -> a -> Either [Char] b
test xs n = if n < 0 then Left "n<0" else Right xs

test2 :: (Typeable a1, Typeable a2) =>
           a1 -> [a2] -> Int -> Either [Char] [a2]
test2 e xs n 
        | n> ( length xs )= Left "n> $ length xs "
        | (typeOf e) /= (typeOf (head xs) ) = Left "(typeOf e) /= (typeOf (head xs) ) "
        |otherwise = Right xs

sf :: Typeable a => a -> [a] -> Int -> Either [Char] [a]
sf e xs n = test xs n >>test2 e xs n >> Right (insert_at e xs n)
```

All the other error got properly handled, expect this.

```
* No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal `1'
    * In the expression: 1
      In the second argument of `sf', namely `[1, 2, 3, 4, ....]'
      In the expression: sf 'a' [1, 2, 3, 4, ....] 3
```

Comment: Small clarification: what exactly are you asking here? Do you want to know why you’re getting the error at the end of your post, or do you have some other problem?

Comment: yes, the error in the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that you're trying to evaluate the expression `sf 'a' [1, 2, 3, 4, ....] 3`. Since this expression is not shown in your question, I'm assuming you're using it in GHCi to test out your code, right?

The type signature of `sf` says that the first parameter has type `a`, and the second parameter has type `[a]`, which is a list whose elements are of the same type as the first parameter.

So the compiler sees that the first parameter is `'a'`. That's a character, type `Char`.

"Got it," - thinks the compiler, - "now I know that `a` is `Char`. And now I know that the second parameter must have type `[Char]` - that is, a list of `Char`".

And yes, the second parameter is indeed a list, but wait! The first element of the list is not a character, but number `1`! That does not compute!

Fortunately, number literals are special in Haskell. Number literals are not merely of type `Int` or even of type `Integer`, no! Numbers can be of *any* type as long as that type has an instance of class `Num`.

So since the compiler already knows that the elements of that list must be of type `Char`, but it sees a number literal, it concludes that it must now find an instance of class `Num` for type `Char`.

But there is no such instance! And so the compiler rightly complains: "*no instance `Num Char`*"

---

To fix the problem, I need to better understand what you were actually trying to do.

Did you intend the whole function to work on numbers? Then the first parameter must be a number, not a character.

Or did you intend it to work on characters? Then the second parameter must be a list of characters, not numbers.

Or did you intend the first two parameters not to be the same type at all? Then you must change the type signature of `sf` to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

`sf` expects a value and a list as its first two arguments. The elements of the list must have the same type as the first argument. This is the meaning of

```
sf :: a -> [a] -> ...
```

When you write `sf 'a' [1]`, this means `1` and `'a'` must have the same type. So the type checker looks for a way to interpret `1` as a `Char`; it fails, because this is not possible. Some fixes might include:

```
sf 'a' "1234" 3
sf 'a' [toEnum 1, toEnum 2, toEnum 3, toEnum 4] 3
sf (fromEnum 'a') [1, 2, 3, 4] 3
```